# How to Quiet an operator to avoid Query fail

Tags: warning-messages, associations, query

This Query fail, due to divide by zero error message...

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0|> // Query[#a/#b &]
```

> Missing["Failed"]

...can be prevented by wrapping `Quiet` around the division:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0|> // Query[Quiet[#a/#b] &]
```

> ComplexInfinity

But will not work if wrapped outside Query.

Is there a way to wrap `Quiet` around operators - eg it's handy to `Apply[...]` some operation around a list:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 2|> // 
 Query[{{"a", "c"}, "c"} /* Apply[Divide]]
```

> <|a->1/2,c->1|>

But

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 2|> // 
 Query[{{"a", "c"}, "b"} /* Apply[Divide]]
```

> Missing["Failed"]

Of course if the operator is deprecated to a function, `Quiet` can be used, but that's not the point here:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 2|> // 
 Query[{{"a", "c"}, "b"} /* Apply[Quiet[Divide[##]] &]]
```

> <|"a" -> ComplexInfinity, "c" -> ComplexInfinity|>

Answer (score 3):

I was going to delete the Q as I realized 2 min after posting that composing with Quiet works: maybe others will find it interesting:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 2|> // 
 Query[{{"a", "c"}, "b"} /* Apply[Divide /* Quiet]]
```

> <|"a" -> ComplexInfinity, "c" -> ComplexInfinity|>

Answer (score 2):

Or `FailureAction -> None` + wrap with `Quiet`:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0|> //  Query[#a/#b &, FailureAction -> None] // Quiet
```

> ```
> ComplexInfinity
> ```

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 2|> // 
   Query[{{"a", "c"}, "b"} /* Apply[Divide], FailureAction -> None] //
   Quiet
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> ComplexInfinity, "c" -> ComplexInfinity|>
> ```